# Why is ExecuteBatchAsync (delete operations) trying to delete twice?

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm attempting to delete multiple rows from an Azure Storage Table using `ExecuteBatchAsync` but it throws an exception - it appears to delete the table entities (*i.e.*, rows), then attempts to delete them again, which causes an exception.

Here is the code:

```
var table = await GetTableAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
var deleteOperations = new TableBatchOperation();
foreach (var tableEntity in GetTableEntities(/* ... */).ToList())
{
    deleteOperations.Add(TableOperation.Delete(tableEntity));
}
try
{
    await table.ExecuteBatchAsync(deleteOperations).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (StorageException exception)
{
    var m = exception.Message;
    throw;
}
```

The call to `ExecuteBatchAsync` takes several seconds when executing against local storage (and I'm testing using only one or two rows), then throws the following `StorageException`:

[image]

You can see the `exception.RequestInformation.HttpStatusMessage`...

> The specified resource does not exist.

And yet the entities *do* get deleted from the table, which makes me believe that it deletes the entities, then attempts to delete them again - and fails on the first entity.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you so sure that `GetTableEntities()`  isn't returning the same entity keys twice?

Comment: (1) Debugging - I can see what it's attempting to do; (2) I've tried it with only a single row in the table.

Comment: Have you used a HTTP proxy, like Fiddler, to check every actual HTTP request that's being exchanged? That would help pin things down.

Comment: While saving/deleting entities I don't see any relevant requests in Fiddler.